# How to match a specific regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a hard time understanding how to match a certain regular expression using javascripts match() function.  I have a field in a table stored in the following format: 
CH-01-Feb-13-1.  I want to be able to grab the date without the dashes, i.e. 01-Feb-13.  I was trying to figure out how to combine with ^- or . but not sure how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean "without the dashes?"  `01-Feb-13` has dashes in it.  We also need more examples of what the starting string looks like.  Does it always start with two letters?  More?  non-letters?  What about what it ends with?

Comment: That is the string, it always starts with two letters, a dash and the date, then a dash and a number.  So I need to ignore the first two letters, the dash, and the last dash and number and be left with the date, i.e. 01-Feb-13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the regular expression?
Something like

```
^\w{2}-(\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{2}).*?$
```

You can see the explanation here: http://www.regexper.com/ Just copy and paste the expression.

[image]

Example with Javascript

```
var r = /^\w{2}-(\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{2}).*?$/i
var groups = "CH-01-Feb-13-1".match(r);
console.log(groups);
```

Comment: Thanks for that website, I was on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp trying to figure out how to combine my expression.

Comment: @trueinViso Use `[1]` to get the first parenthesized submatch, in this case `01-Feb-13`. To remove dashes from this, you can then do `.replace(/\-/g, " ")`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not comfortable with Regex then you can use something like this.

```
var str = 'CH-01-Feb-13-1';
str = str.replace('CH-','');
str = str.split('-');
str.pop();
console.log(str.join('-'));
```